# Can I install MySQL on the VMs provided in Azure Cloud Services?

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

From what I gather, the only way to use a MySQL database with Azure websites is to use Cleardb but can I install MySQL on VMs provided in Azure Cloud Services. And if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question might get closed and moved to ServerFault (where it really belongs). That said: ClearDB provides MySQL-as-a-Service in Azure. It has nothing to do with what you can install in your own Virtual Machines. You can absolutely do a VM-based MySQL install (or any other database engine that you can install on Linux or Windows). In fact, the Azure portal even has a [tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-mysql-use-opensuse/) for a MySQL installation on OpenSUSE.

If you're referring to installing in web/worker roles: This simply isn't a good fit for database engines, due to:

- the need to completely script/automate the install with zero interaction (which might take a long time). This includes *all* necessary software being downloaded/installed to the vm images every time a new instance is spun up.
- the likely inability for a database cluster to cope with arbitrary scale-out (the typical use case for web/worker roles). Database clusters may or may not work well when a scale-out occurs (adding an additional vm). Same thing when scaling in (removing a vm).
- less-optimal attached-storage configuration
- inability to use Linux VMs

So, assuming you're still ok with Virtual Machines (vs stateless Cloud Service vm's): You'll need to carefully plan your deployment, with decisions such as:

- Distro (Ubuntu, CentOS, etc). Azure-supported Linux distro list [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-endorsed-distributions/)
- Selecting proper VM size (the DS series provide SSD attached disk support; the G series scale to 448GB RAM)
- Azure Storage attached disks being non-Premium or Premium (premium disks are SSD-backed, durable disks scaling to 1TB/5000 IOPS per disk, up to 32 disks per VM depending on VM size)
- Virtual network configuration (for multi-node cluster)
- Accessibility of database cluster (whether your app is in the vnet or accesses it through a public endpoint; and if the latter, setting up ACL's)
- Backup / HA / DR planning

Someone else mentioned using a pre-built VM image from VM Depot. Just realize that, if you go that route, you're relying on someone else to configure the database engine install for you. This may or may not be optimal for what you're trying to achieve. And the images may or may not be up-to-date with the latest versions, patches, etc.

Of course, what I wrote applies to any database engine you install in your own virtual machines, where a service provider (such as ClearDB) tends to take care of most of these things for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about standard VMs then you can use a [pre-built images on VMDepot](https://vmdepot.msopentech.com/List/Index?sort=Featured&search=mysql) for that.

If you are talking about web or worker roles (PaaS) I wouldn't recommend it, but if you really want to you could.  You would need to fully script the install of the solution on the host. The only downside (and it's a big one) you would have would be the that the host will be moved to a new host at some point which would mean your MySQL data files would be lost - if you backed up frequently and were happy to lose some data then this option may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the main question is "what You want to achieve?". As I see, You want to use PaaS solution with Web Apps or Cloud Service and You need a MySQL database. If Yes, You have two options (both technically as David Makogon said). First one is to deploy Your own (one) server with MySQL and connect to it from the outside (internet side). Second solution is to create one MySQL server or cluster and connect Your application internally in Azure virtual network. WIth Cloud Service it is simple but with Web App it is not. You must create VPN gateway in Azure VM and connect Your Web App to this gateway. In this way You will have internal connection wfrom Your application to Your own MySQL cluster.